# Copy elision in range based for loops

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-elision

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    A() {    
    }

    A(const A &a) {
        cout << "Copied!" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   vector<A> vec;
   vec.push_back(A());
   vec.push_back(A());
   vec.push_back(A());
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;

   for (A &a: vec) {
       cout << "loop1" <<endl;
   }
   for (A a: vec) {
       cout << "loop2" <<endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I ran this program and it printed:

```
Copied!
Copied!
Copied!
Hello World
loop1
loop1
loop1
Copied!
loop2
Copied!
loop2
Copied!
loop2
```

My question is why was Copied printed at all? When calling `push_back(A())` why isn't the copy elided? In the line `for (A a: vec)` why isn't the copy elided?

I am compiling with the following command:
`sh-4.3# g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o main  *.cpp`

Comment: Copy elision applies in a narrow, specific set of circumstances. It's not a universal magic rule to "make the program more efficient based on what I mean".

Comment: Is there a danger for the compiler in optimizing in these cases? Why not elide the copies here?

Comment: It's not allowed to! Your copy constructor has side effects, and generally the compiler has to assume that you want your program to do what you write. As I said, there are only a *very limited* set of circumstances under which the compiler is allowed to ignore what you mean and produce a program that behaves *differently*.

Comment: The side effects don't inhibit the copy elision. As can be seen in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision.

Comment: @Benjy: They don't inhibit copy elision in scenarios were copy elision actually takes place, no. But our desire to see our side effects most of the time is the reason that copy elision doesn't take place in _this_ scenario, or the vast majority of others. Which is what Kerrek said already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply because there is no rule to allow copy elision in this case.

It's generally only allowed when returning a value from a function, or when *copy-initialising*. In every other case, where a copy has side-effects (such as your I/O), copy elision is prohibited.

It would be madness for the standard to make the rule so lax that *any* copy may be prohibited no matter what a copy's side effects were: you'd lose any ability to rationalise about your program deterministically. Besides, it is computationally infeasible in the general case for your compiler to determine that it's even safe to to do so.

An exception solely for loops, or solely for loops that do not use the looped-over value, would be illogically arbitrary.